# Создание таблицы в C#

Tags: c#, winforms, datagridview

У меня 3 вопроса:

1. Можно ли создать таблицу в WinForms отличную от DataGridView (другим
       способом, т.к. там нет возможности устанавливать количество строк)?
2. Допустим, для примера, я добавил в форму DataGridView1. Как с
   помощью кнопки уже в самой программе можно добавлять ещё несколько
   таких же таблиц с теми же свойствами?
3. Допустим, я в нескольких таблицах ввёл какие-то числа. Как сделать,
   чтобы одинаковые числа в разных таблицах выделялись другим цветом,
   или выделялись ячейки таблицы, в которых находятся похожие числа?

Comment: (2) А в чём проблема? Если вы можете добавить одну таблицу, что вам мешает добавить точно такую же другую точно таким же кодом?

Comment: (3) Руками, всё руками. Пройдитесь по значениям, найдите нужные, обновите UI.

Comment: Во-первых, такая таблица не подходит, т.к. там нет возможности добавлять строки, т.е. заранее определить как должна выглядеть таблица, сколько столбцов и строк. Я хотел узнать можно ли другим способом её создать с заранее определёнными свойствами. Во-вторых, "ручками, всё ручками" это очень понятный и развёрнутый ответ, не знал, что всё так просто.

Comment: (3) Ну, смысл в том, что встроенных средств по идее нету, так что вам придётся самостоятельно подписаться на изменение данных и перекрашивать ячейки. Как именно это делать, наверняка есть в документации. Если бы я точно знал, я бы написал _развёрнутый_ ответ, а не комментарий.